# Ajax call to HTTPS failing

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, https, spring-security

I am trying to call my Spring-MVC controller which will be responsible to go ahead with login/authorization mechanism using Spring security.

here are the requirements

1. Spring security need to have request from HTTPS else it will throw an error.

i followed the following tutorial to accomplish this [/implementing_ajax_authentication_using_jquery](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/implementing_ajax_authentication_using_jquery).

here is my piece of Jquery code

```
jQuery("#loginForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "https://localhost:9002/myApp/springSecurity/login.json",
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.withCredentials = true;
            },
            type: "POST",
            data: jQuery("#loginForm").serialize(),
            dataType: 'application/json',

            success: function(data, status) {

                if (data.loggedIn) {
                   // location.href = getHost() + '${ctx}/users';
                    //login_pannel
                    alert("jai ho");
                } else {
                    loginFailed(data);
                }
            },
            error: loginFailed
        });

    });
```

In order to handle  cross domain problem i have created a Filter and placed it in my web.xml with following entries

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://" + req.getServerName());
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "360");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

### Spring Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public SpringSecurityLoginStatus login(@RequestParam("j_username") final String username,
            @RequestParam("j_password") final String password, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
    {

        LOG.info("Starting login process");
        return springSecurityLoginService.login(username, password, request, response);
    }
```

But i am undergoing a strange problem, when i am hitting the submit button, browser is sending request to the secure URL like `https://localhost:9002/myApp/springSecurity/login.json` but my Controller method is never getting called and in fact this is error i saw in by Mozilla error console

[image]

After looking at the console it seems like browser is calling again with GET method which seems like a redirect.

I am not sure why this is happening and why browser is doing a redirect from HTTPS to HTTP using GET request silently

Here is the output from Mozila net pannel

### Response Headersview source

```
Access-Control-Allow-Cred...    true
Access-Control-Allow-Head...    x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    GET,POST
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    https://localhost
Access-Control-Max-Age  360
Content-Length  0
Date    Thu, 14 Jun 2012 11:12:36 GMT
Location    http://localhost:9001/myapp/springSecurity/login.json
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie  _system.tenantID_=""; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/
Request Headersview source
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  JSESSIONID=26BEEB7DC056D2A5F08D107E3D4BCDDB; __atuvc=4|22; secureGUID=60be684d748027c1f567eadead08f28771ab7d25; JSESSIONID=4E2300220697C799AF4539ABCB9108DD
Host    localhost:9002
Referer http://localhost:9001/myapp/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
```

### Response Headers From Cache

```
Access-Control-Allow-Cred...    true
Access-Control-Allow-Head...    x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    GET,POST
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    https://localhost
Access-Control-Max-Age  360
Content-Length  0
Date    Thu, 14 Jun 2012 11:12:36 GMT
Location    http://localhost:9001/myapp/springSecurity/login.json
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie  _system.tenantID_=""; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/
```

on a side note if i change the URL `http://localhost:9001/myapp/springSecurity/login.json` i.e to HTTP protocol, its able to call my Controller.

### Respone Class

```
public class SpringSecurityLoginStatus
{

    private final boolean loggedIn;
    private final String username;

    public SpringSecurityLoginStatus(final boolean loggedIn, final String username)
    {
        this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn()
    {
        return loggedIn;
    }

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't implemented 'GET' method for the url 'login.json'.

If you look at your controller it implements only `POST` request method, but your request type is `GET` that is why you are getting this error.

Can you share the return value of your `login` method?

It looks like you are returning a `302 moved temporarily` status from your login method.

Comment: I am not sure why i need a GET method, since my idea was to trigger spring security authentication process and return back the status.I am not sure about the request type as `GET` since i have mentioned it as `POST`.Here is the signature of my Login method`@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST) @ResponseBody
public SpringSecurityLoginStatus login(@RequestParam("j_username") final String username,@RequestParam("j_password") final String password, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response){/impl}`. Well i am not returning `302` from my controller and it never cal

Comment: The problem looks like the value returned by your `login` method. Can you explain the returned value? And also share the response headers. what do you want to do after a successfull login?

Comment: Return type is a simple POJO with 2 fields, 1 is a boolean value and other is a String

Comment: Can you share the returned value and the response headers? Can you also tell me what is happening inside  `springSecurityLoginService.login()`, are you setting any response status inside that method?

Comment: i have updated the question and inside `springSecurityLoginService.login()`i am just using the Spring Security login mechanism.My biggest surprise is that when sending request from `HTTPS` my controller never get called and it ask for `GET` method while using HTTP its working fine, but failing in spring security

Comment: Which servlet container are you using? did you configure https in it?

Comment: I am using Tomcat and yes HTTPS is working perfectly fine on it

Comment: Can you share the response headers? then it looks like when a https request is coming some how the application is getting redirected to http url. Is your loggin page working fine with https? You can get the response headers from firefox console log

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12547/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-user728947)

Comment: My Login page working perfectly with HTTPS mechanism and i have updated my post with the response header.